# get data attribute from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i am tring to modify this sortlist to sort by most recent date from a data attribute.

```
function sortList(ul) {
   var ul = document.getElementById(ul);
   Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("div"))
   .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
   .forEach(div => ul.appendChild(div));
}
```

and here is the html

```
 <div class="grid customer-card-cnt" id="customerlist">
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2014-05-10"></div>
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2022-05-10"></div>
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2021-05-10"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're sorting using the wrong property i.e. `textContent` instead of the value of the `data-date` attribute. I've modified your example below to show the correct sort function.

```js
function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);
  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("div"))
    .sort((a, b) => b.dataset.date.localeCompare(a.dataset.date))
    .forEach((div) => ul.appendChild(div));
}
```

This should produce the following html:

```html
 <div class="grid customer-card-cnt" id="customerlist">
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2022-05-10"></div>
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2021-05-10"></div>
     <div class="col col-sm col-4" data-date="2014-05-10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that answered the question